# Hosting a subdirectory of my current website on its own domain name

Tags: wordpress, redirects, subdomain, godaddy, domain-forwarding

## The situation

I have a hosting service (one.com) on which I have installed a `wordpress.org` site in a subdirectory `wordpress`:

```
myhost.example/wordpress/
```

(`myhost.example` is actually my own domain, but it already has contents and I don't want `wordpress/` to appear in the root of that domain.)

I want to use a second domain for this site. Thinking I would be able to forward to the WordPress site without problems, I registered the domain at `GoDaddy.com`:

```
mydomain.example
```

## What I want

So when my visitors type in `mydomain.example`, I want them to see the contents on `myhost.example/wordpress/`, and the same for all subpages (`mydomain.example/a/subpage` fetches from `myhost.example/wordpress/a/subpage`).

Just a redirect isn't enough, I want my visitors to see only `mydomain.example` as their domain.

## Some notes

- If I set up forward *with URL masking* at GoDaddy, they just give a full frame, pointing to `myhost.example/wordpress/`. This isn't good enough for me, since `mydomain.example` will always show up in the address bar, also for subpages (I want `mydomain.example/a/subpage` to show in the address bar for a subpage).
- I believe this could in principle be done with a `.htaccess` file with URL rewriting, but I have no hosting with GoDaddy so I can't upload such a file there. Hosting with GoDaddy is very expensive (of course) so I don't want to do that.
- I don't think I can use DNS settings; the host of `mydomain.example` says they don't allow anyone else to point to their name servers.
- If possible, I wouldn't want to re-install the WordPress site, it would take quite some time. I'd prefer to keep it at `myhost.example/wordpress/` (if possible)
- Anything involving transferring the domain is supposed to take 5-7 working days. I would need my site up-and-running earlier than that, so I'd like to avoid it if possible.

## Am I locked in?

As it seems, I am rather locked-in with GoDaddy. I can't use the domain with `.htaccess` since I can't upload such a file (and won't pay for hosting by GoDaddy). I can't use any of their forward options since none of them do what I want (one just forwards, the one that masks the URL does it with frames).

Would you agree?

## Possible solutions

- Transfer the domain to any hosting service with reasonable hosting pricing, as opposed to GoDaddy (I'd probably use one.com, the same host as for `myhost.example`, in that case), and there either

  - re-install WordPress on the new account, or
  - use `.htaccess` with URL rewrite on the new account to fetch the contents from `myhost.example/wordpress/`. Can this be set-up to work with sub-pages as well? And visitors won't ever see `myhost.example/wordpress`, just `mydomain.example`? E.i., `mydomain.example/a/subpage/` wold fetch from `myhost.example/wordpress/a/subpage/`?
- This might be a long shot but:

  - Find some free (preferably) hosting allowing to point to their name servers
  - Make DNS settings at GoDaddy so that my domain appears at the site above
  - at that site, put a `.htaccess` file with URL rewriting to forward to `myhost.example/wordpress/`
    Could this be possible? What services could I use in that case? As I see it, this would be the only way not to have to transfer a domain (taking 5-7 working days) *and* not having to re-install the WordPress site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to take a look at Apache [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html)

ex.

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>`
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
#someone requests mydomain.example 
  ProxyPass / http://myhost.example/wordpress
  ProxyPassReverse / http://myhost.example/wordpress
```

this is if you can get a host just for `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure One won't let you point multiple domains (from whatever registrar) to the root of your site? For instance, I use GoDaddy's Economy Shared plan (cheapest/least features). I can have unlimited addon domains, but they all have to point to root. It's a very simple `.htaccess` trick that forwards my domains to their approrpriate subdirectories. I currently have 7 WordPress installs, all accessible from different domains, masked with `.htaccess`.

As an aside, I don't know what One charges per month, but with GoDaddy I got a 3 month deal for US$1.99/month. After that I pay $5/month. If you're able to afford it, that might be a better option if One doesn't let you point other domains to your root.

Answer (score 0):

This should ordinarily be quite a simple process...

- Change the NAMESERVERS of `mydomain.example` (at GoDaddy) to point to the DNS at `myhost.example`
- Setup an Add-On domain in your hosting account at `myhost.example` to point `mydomain.example` at your /wordpress sub directory (which needs to be set up as a subdomain).

However, looking at the [FAQ at one.com](http://www.one.com/en/support/faq/can-i-have-several-domains-on-one-web-hotel)...

> **Can I have several domains on one web space?**
>
> No. Unfortunately, we are unable to provide several domains on one web
> space. It will however be possible to set up an additional web space
> and add a script which forwards the relevant domain/web space to a
> different domain/web space. This does however require two
> subscriptions.

GoDaddy does not appear to be the problem, since [they allow you to update the DNS](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/664/setting-nameservers-for-your-domain-names). The problem appears to be with your host (one.com)

---

As an alternative (quick fix) you could perhaps setup a subdomain instead? eg. `blog.myhost.example` could show the content from `myhost.example/wordpress`. This of course doesn't involve `mydomain.example`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this would mean that I could add another subscription at one.com and do exactly what you suggest? I guess this would niether require to wait the 5-7 working days for a domain transfer, nor require reinstalling wordpress(?).

Comment: Ultimately you will need to clarify this with one.com, but I am not convinced this is what you are after. In my mind a "forward" would simply _redirect_ requests (probably using .htaccess) from "mydomain.com" to "myhost.com/wordpress" <-- and that is what will be shown in the address bar of the browser. But isn't "two subscriptions" the same as two hosting accounts and hence twice the expense? Although a hassle, you could install wordpress on the 2nd subscription?

Comment: About your "edit" suggestion: A good idea, but I need to start use/promoting my site, and I need the right domain for that.

Comment: Your comment: Yes, that would be twice the expenses, but we're not talking big money here, that could be OK.

But once I can upload an .htaccess file, won't I be able to code it with apropriate URL rewrites so everything `mydomain.com/any/subpage` will automatically fetch/request from `one.com/my-new-account/any/subpage`... with "masking", so that the visitor never sees anything like `one.com/my-new-account` etc. ?

Comment: If these are two completely separate accounts then you won't be able to do an internal rewrite ("masking") from one domain to the other, you can only do an external redirect. If this was possible then what would stop _anyone_ from setting up another account and stealing (masking) all your content?